# Faradays constant determination?

Tags: physical-chemistry, history, physical-constants, metrology

I am a bit confused on how faraday determined his [constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_constant). So I’ve been taught that he realized that if you sent a certain amount of charge (96485 C), then one mole (or some fraction of that based on the ionization) of a substance would be deposited. But how did he know what one mole of a substance was because Avogadro’s number was found by dividing the faraday by the charge of an electron. So it seems like a little bit of circular definition? Like if he used silver, how did he know what 1 mole of silver was because he couldn’t know what the molar mass of silver is if Avogadro’s number hadn’t been found then?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs in history of physics/chemistry.

Comment: @Gert I don't agree the question is about history. Its first words
(*how faraday determined his constant*) could be read that way but
when the OP writes *how did he know what 1 mole of silver was because he couldn't know what the molar mass of silver is if Avogadro's number hadn't been found then?* his question becomes one about *logic* of the matter. He's in need of understanding that there are several possible definitions of molar mass, among which those involving only ratios of masses participating in a reaction.

Comment: @Gert Avogadro's constant isn't necessarily involved and actually it didn't, for a long time. But this *isn't* a historical matter.

Comment: @ElioFabri This reads history-based to me. This could certainly be edited into a form that asks explicitly (and only) about the logic, but the current text reads history-based.